# Forge Viewer Appearance Diff Between File Types

Tags: autodesk-viewer, revit-api, autodesk, forge, viewer

When uploading the same model but converted to various extensions we get a different look in the Forge Viewer. Specifically, we like the look of models brought into Forge through Revit but the same model brought in as FBX or Rhino has a lower quality appearance. We lose the subtleties that we enjoy in the Revit > Forge pipeline. Does anyone know why the resulting SVF format as a different appearance and how to, perhaps, make the Forge viewer look more like the Revit > Forge workflow? I will attach a few image comparisons. I did try bringing the Rhino into Revit and it looks how we want but a lot of the attribution and individual models are lost on import to Revit.

Answer (score 0):

The Model Derivative service can ingest over 60 different file formats today, but of course, every file format provides a different "level of detail" and "precision". Certain file formats only describe surface materials with diffuse/specular color, other file formats provide full physically-based material models. And even if two file formats use physically-based materials, they may be using different mathematical models...

So, while the Model Derivative service is doing its best to bring as much of the original material description over to Forge Viewer, you may not always get the same results.

Btw. you can always apply custom materials to your models to improve the visual quality if needed. Here's a blog post that talks about "material swatches", allowing you to apply better-looking materials from Fusion to other models: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/material-swatches-forge-viewer.